# SQL Server Login

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

What is the SQL query to check whether particular SQL Login is Enable or Disable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT is_disabled FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = @name;
```

Updated after OP question:

'guest' is not a login (server principal) is an user (database principal) so you need to look for it in [`sys.database_principals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx). Users cannot be enabled nor disabled, they simply exist or don't exist. `guest` is a special built-in user that maps all server principals that are not explicitly mapped to another user: that is server principals (logins) that have access to the database but do not have a database principal (user) with a matching SID will be mapped to 'guest'. Except members of sysadmin role which are always mapped to `dbo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, type_desc, is_disabled
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE name = 'sa'
```

Replace 'sa' with your desired login.

Comment: When i run the below Query its doesn't show me the guest user status, where its enable or disable. 

SELECT name, type_desc, is_disabled 
FROM sys.server_principals